# jQuery ui tabs animate change in height between tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I'm trying to create a simple tabbed interface using the tabs plugin from the jQuery ui library. I have the tabs working fine but I need the change in height when the user clicks to a new tab to ease up or down. Something just like [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/OrganicTabs/) but using jQuery ui tabs plugin.

So far I'm using the basic script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

Comment: IF you just posted your best try, you could learn something new, we would be glad to point some issues you had in your code. Now someone would probably build it all for you or you won't get an answer at all...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({ fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 1000 } });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use some effects in jquery ui,
       $( ".selector" ).tabs({ hide: { effect: "explode", duration: 1000 } });

Refer this, http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/